# What is the recommended strategy to implement a subset id in a scheduled task?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I plan to implement a scheduled task that takes all account entries for the past day and clones them with the date of the current day. The `accountId` should reamin the same so that I can later get a track record for the account movements.

I was thinking about the following two possibilities to create the `accountId`:

1. Using Foreing Key
2. Using a custom routine that creates `accountId` during the `createAccount` workflow

What is the recommended strategy to handle the generation of `accountId`? Does Spring Boot/JPA already provide annotations that I could use to auto-increment the `accountId` during the `createAccount`?

Below are the basic structures of my entity and service classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class AccountEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "account_id")
    private Long accountId; 

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "date")
    private LocalDate date;

    
}
```

```
@Service
public class AccountService { 
    public createAccount() {
    //Create a new account with new accountId
    }
    
    @Scheduled()
    public createSnapshot() {
    //Duplicate already saved entries with with new date, do not change accountId
    }

}
```